# How to run a function in python that has a time limit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, time

So I'm trying to create a program that would gather user input in a certain period of time. For example, when I start the function, the timer should also start. As soon as the timer ends and the user doesn't give any input the program would jump to different function instead. If the user does give an input before the timer ends, it does another function instead. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use multithreading with one thread starting a timer and the other thread dealing with the input

Comment: you could have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31667005/9903391